# file_get_contents with http - Failed to open stream

Tags: php, http, web, fopen

I try to get the text from a website with the `file_get_contents()`-function in PHP.

```
        $myVariable = file_get_contents('myUrl/json/file.json?jsonp=loadSomething);
```

Unfortunately I keep getting the message

```
"Warning:
file_get_contents(myUrl/json/file.json?jsonp=loadSomething): 
failed to open stream: HTTP request failed! 
HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found in *path of my .php- file* on line 10"
```

In php.ini, allow_url_fopen is set to "On". I also already tried `urlencode()`.
What can I do to get my code working?

Comment: and you, i.e the www-user have read-access to that directory?

Comment: How do you mean? The code is in the "helper.php"-file of a module, installed on my Joomla-page, so I believe, the www-user has read-access.

Comment: I mean, do you have proper user rights on `json/`? However, try use an absolute path if you not have done that yet.

Comment: The file I try to open is on another website. I can open the URL in my browser without problems, it displays a plain text message to me. And this is the message, I want to save in my variable. So as a www-user I do have access to the "file.json".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK, the remote file *is* accessible. When `file_get_contents` fails, [**cURL**](http://php.net/manual/en/book.curl.php) is your friend :

```php
function file_get_contents_curl($url) {
    $curl = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; Windows NT 5.1; SV1; .NET CLR 1.0.3705; .NET CLR 1.1.4322)');
    $data = curl_exec($curl);
    curl_close($curl);
    return $data;
}
```

now try

```
$myVariable = file_get_contents_curl('myUrl/json/file.json?jsonp=loadSomething');
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I do not get any warnings or errors right now, but still, I don't receive the text of the website properly. Calling the function only appears to return "0".

Comment: @msu-welle - I begin to believe your remote site actively try to prevent scraping and such ... See update, trying to fake your call is made by a browser by `CURLOPT_USERAGENT`.